# django syncdb fails and does not know my module

Tags: python, django

I use 64bit Python 3.4 in 64bit Windows 7 and Django 1.8.3.
I created a module named blog and edited INSTALLED_APP part in settings.py as follow:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'mysite01.blog',)
```

but when I run " python manage.py syncdb " I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 114, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'blog'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_co
mmand_line
utility.execute()
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "D:\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib
\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ImportError: No module named 'mysite01.blog'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Rename mysite01.blog as blog in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: well, Thanks @GeoJacob, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GeoJacob the error was removed by editing settings.py as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'blog',)
```

but in order to creating the table of the model in db this command was necessary before syncdb:

```
>python manage.py makemigrations
```